# CKEditor escape html

Tags: html, escaping, ckeditor, pre

I have CKEditor on post text where I want to insert html-code. Something like this:

```
<pre>
<code class="html">
<img src="path/to/img.jpg" />
</code>
</pre>
```

But when I save the text, CKEditor interprets img-tag as actual html-image and shows broken image. How I can prevent that and tell to escape html-code in **pre-code** block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<pre>
<code class="html">
<img src="path/to/img.jpg" />
</code>
</pre>
```

This is **an image** inside a `pre` element. What you want to create is:

```
<pre>
<code class="html">
&lt;img src="path/to/img.jpg" /&gt;
</code>
</pre>
```

And if you write `<img .../>` inside `pre` element in CKEditor, then CKEditor will return this (valid) HTML.

What developers often don't know is that when they load that content from their database into `<textarea>` this content may need to be encoded (depends on how it's saved). In PHP for instance it's enough to pass it through `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: But I need only to escape html-characters inside pre-code block. Can CKEditor do that for me? (Of course I can parse the whole post text and escape these chars on server-side but maybe there is some option or plugin to tell ckeditor what must be done)

Comment: No - there's no option and I don't know about plugin that does this. Such plugin would be tricky to implement, because that content must be encoded only once, not every time data is loaded. Moreover, in some cases people really want to create elements inside `<code>` tags and such plugin would break them.