# CKeditor: escape Html when saving (make it unrunnable on load)

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

bit of an issue with ckeditor. 
If i save

```
<body onload="alert('test');">
```

to the DB, on reload, the code runs and a browser alert is triggered. I'd like for CKeditor to add some formatting to the text before saving so it cannot run on load. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907988/ckeditor-escape-html?rq=1) post is tangentially related but not quite relevant. 
Cheers

Comment: check this out > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065731/ckeditor-remove-script-tag-with-data-processor

Comment: Do you just want to get rid of the bad parts (like the alert) or do you just want to display all html as plain text?

Comment: @TiiJ7 as plain text. I don't want to do anything to user data. I just want ckeditor to add some "escape syntax" to it before saving so that when the browser loads the data it doesn't run.

Comment: @minam.cho, that question has no approved answer and the answer doesn't even work, unfortunately . It's also not really what i want to do. I do not want to remove the script tag. I just don't want it to run when loaded. It shouls really just be text.

Comment: In that case usually the recommendation is to store the user's data as-is and do the actual html escaping when the data is being displayed. This is of course done on the server side rather than in the client (like CKEditor). And even if you decide to escape the html before saving it to the database, it would probably still be better to do it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to encode your data (treat it as best practice). From CKEditor point of view, you can only use [htmlEncodeOutput](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-htmlEncodeOutput) however as @TiiJ7 has explained it, you should also make sure that your server-side code will return encoded data to CKEditor. By encoded I mean that special HTML characters should be changed into entities as shown below (just like in every sample in `ckeditor/samples/old` ):

```
    &lt;html&gt;
        &lt;head&gt;
            &lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;
        &lt;/head&gt;
        &lt;body onload=&quot;alert('test');&quot;&gt;
        &lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
```

---

Taking the best practices aside, one thing which wonders me is that why this `alert` gets executed in your case. I'm asking because even if you paste below not-encoded HTML  in source mode (or even load such HTML):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body onload="alert('test');">&nbsp;</body>
</html>
```

and then switch to wysiwyg mode, you will not get any `alert` message as it will be automatically put into `data-cke-pa-onload` attribute. You can verify that in nightly sample - http://nightly.ckeditor.com/18-06-25-06-04/full/samples/old/wysiwygarea/fullpage.html and in the screen-shot below.

[image]

Are you using some third-party plugins which cause that or you have customized your CKEditor so that alerts now get executed? In such a case using latest and default version might help.